# Dynamic inputs in function

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I need to do number of inputs that it dynamic's number , and for every input other name because I want to use in these inputs.

I call to the function in jsx with that

```
Array.apply(null, { length:  numberInputs}).map((e, i) => (
    <InputsNumber key={i} />
  ))
```

and I tried do for loop but because the function InputsNumber return tags of html it doesn't work well and the number is dynamic but all the number there same as my dynamic's number inputs

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
const dynamicInputs = (numberInputs) => {
    return Array.apply(null, { length: numberInputs }).map((e, i) => (
        <InputsNumber key={i} />
    ))
}
```

Comment: can't do function on react's component when there return tags

Comment: You can do it outside your component and call the function inside

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
const dynamicFunc = (number) => {
    return Array.apply(null, {number}).map((num, index) => (
         <InputsNumber key={index} />
    ))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did useState with the object of the inputs that I want and added on click on the button "add inputs" more object and then I did map on this useState its looks like this :

[image]

Comment: Just like with questions, code in answers should be posted as text, not a picture

Comment: couldn't understand how to do code in my answer

Comment: When you posted your answer, you should have seen a help button. Click it and it gives help with formatting, and links you to a tutorial on markdown. You could have also looked at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Even plain unformatted text that someone else could format for you would be preferable to a picture